# Koi Pond Needs Emptied due to safety issues

Tags: pond

We have a fairly large koi pond that needs converted to something more safe for 2 year old. It has a top and side fountain that run into it. We've wondered about removing the koi and placing a larger sized river rock in the water to where they can be walked on,  allowing possibly 2" of water above rock, but still allowing the fountains to flow? Someday we'd like to use the pond for koi again. Would this work?

Comment: Can’t answer the technical question, but note that especially small children can drown in very shallow water and even after being pulled out (“dry drowning”, caused by spasms of the vocal cords). Even if it looks ugly for a while, a fence and/or a sturdy net might be a solution for a few years, blocking access to the water. For your plans, a photo and perhaps a sketch might make your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @stephnie that a fence / net would be the best, not to mention easiest.  I would also think about a gate (or serverel) so you can introduce your child to the waterfall, and eventually the pond as they grow over the next few years.

I'm having a hard time imagining how big/small this pond is, but add a single rock to it sounds difficult, expensive, and probably permanent.  You could add smaller rocks, and/or gravel to fill the pond, but it's likely not a small project.

The only things that I can recommend watching out for are the intake(s) for the waterfalls, and/or the intake for the filter system.  If you block those, or they get clogged it could be headache.  You might also think about bypassing your filter system or installing a smaller filter system as you're be filling much less water, and not needing to support fish.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of a well anchored, strong net being placed over a pond . It can be walked on and is only depressed a couple inches into the water. It would not affect filtering , etc. Of course , one can drown in 2 inches of water.

Answer (score 1):

You could drain it, make a false bottom, and repurpose it as a sand pit.

Answer (score 1):

My neighbour was asked to make his pond safe by the Council so he used that metal mesh that is used for reinforcing concrete so he still had a view of his fish, and didn't have to build a pool fence.